# Problema con @RequestHeader

Tags: java, spring

Os comento mi problema:

Tengo este encabezado

`[{content-length=1344, X_ENTRYPOINT_DOMAIN=de-xxxx.xxxxxx:8555, Accept=*/*, X_ASO_ENTRYPOINT_GROUP=DE, User-Agent=PostmanRuntime/7.6.0, Connection=keep-alive, consumerRequestId=pruebaks Host=de-xxx.xxxxx:7050, X_ENTRYPOINT_DOMAIN_R=de-xxxx.xxxxxx:7050, Content-Type=application/json}]`

Necesito obtener el valor `"X_ENTRYPOINT_DOMAIN"`, he puesto en el controlado de mi servicio la siguiente anotación

```
@RequestHeader(value = "X_ENTRYPOINT_DOMAIN")
```

Y me está devolviendo los 2 values de los key que coinciden :

`X_ENTRYPOINT_DOMAIN=de-xxxx.xxxxxx:8555 X_ENTRYPOINT_DOMAIN_R=de-xxxx.xxxxxx:7050`

Por favor me podrían ayudar. Por el momento he solucionado mi problema con esto pero no me parece adecuado , ya que funciona por es el primer valor que me interesa.

```
headers.getFirst("X_ENTRYPOINT_DOMAIN");
```

¿Cómo podría obtener el valor especifico mediante alguna anotación de spring?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código de como estás usando @RequestHeader? Se ve los parámetros que le pasas, pero no se ve qué es lo que estás anotando. Podría ayudar a entender cuál es el problema.